# Issue with image caching on apache 2

Tags: .htaccess, caching, apache2

I have added next directives to root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/html  "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
```

However, nothing works, all of the images are still not cached. I see that somehow cache works because js and css files are cached but not images. I've searched all htaccess on my website and also checked all `.conf` files in the `etc` folder but can't find what overwrites that rule.

What else can cause such an issue?

Comment: Just admited that everything caches on USA region but images isn't cached on Canada region.

Comment: Are you trying multiple browsers? Maybe the browser you're testing in has caching disabled, or half disabled?

Comment: Yes, I checked it on all browsers I had: Chrome, Mozilla, Opera.